# Give access to Docker Swarm cluster

Tags: docker, authorization, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Okay, here is my situation:

I created a cluster of docker swarm using docker machine. I can deploy any container, etc. So basically everything is working fine. My question right now is how to give access to the cluster to someone else. I want other people to deploy container on that cluster using docker-compose.

Comment: How exactly did you set up Swarm?

Comment: This was setup on a cloud provider (DO). Created a consul KV for service discovery then created master, and nodes, all using docker-machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker machine configures the docker engine on each node to be secured using TLS:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

The client configuration can be seen when running the "docker-machine config" command, for example the following settings are used to access the remote docker host:

```
--tlsverify 
--tlscacert="~/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem" 
--tlscert="~/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem" 
--tlskey="~/.docker/machine/certs/key.pem" 
-H=tcp://....
```

It's the files under *~/.docker/machine/certs* that are needed by other users who want to connect to your swarm.

I expect that docker will eventually create some form of user authentication and authorization.

Comment: So, basically you have to give the pem files to other developers?

Comment: @mateeyow I'm not defending the solution. Swarm is missing features for user authentication and authorization. To get these today you need to purchase a commercial product like twistlock: https://www.twistlock.com/. I expect swarm to improve over time.